# Polling future with another task waker

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement a sink wrapper that delegates flushing to another task. Basically:

- wrapper spawns a service task when constructed
- service task in a loop runs `flush()` on underlying stream and pauses if `poll_flush()` returns `Ready`
- when client sends data into the wrapped sink, it `feed()`s data to underlying sink and then calls `inner.poll_flush()` with a context holding waker for service task

Idea should be pretty clear -- clients do not need to bother with flushing the sink and yet it get flushed automatically as soon as underlying socket/whatever becomes ready.

(to avoid dealing with multi-threading issues assume all this happens within the same `LocalSet`)

I can't figure out how to built aforementioned `Waker` for service task -- is it even possible in Tokio? If not -- is it possible to ask runtime to wake up another task using it's handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct LocalNotify {
    is_on: bool,
    waker: Option<Waker>,
}

impl LocalNotify {
    fn delegate_poll<T, F: FnOnce(&mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T>>(
        &mut self,
        f: F,
    ) -> Option<T> {
        let w = self.waker.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|| noop_waker_ref());
        match f(&mut Context::from_waker(w)) {
            Poll::Pending => {
                self.is_on = true;
                None
            },
            Poll::Ready(r) => Some(r),
        }
    }



    fn notify(&mut self) {
        if !self.is_on {
            self.is_on = true;
            self.waker.take().map(|w| w.wake());
        }
    }

    fn poll_notified(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<()> {
        if self.is_on {
            self.is_on = false;
            self.waker = None;
            return Poll::Ready(());
        } else {
            if self.waker.as_ref().map_or(true, |w| !w.will_wake(cx.waker())) {
                self.waker = Some(cx.waker().clone());
            }
            return Poll::Pending;
        }
    }

    async fn notified(&mut self) {
        poll_fn(|cx| self.poll_notified(cx)).await
    }
}
```

So, if you want to delegate `poll_flush` wakeup to another task (that is waiting on `LocalNotify`) you can:

```
fn poll_send(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>, item: &String) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
    ...
    ready!(<MyStream as SinkExt<String>>::poll_ready_unpin(inner, cx))?;

    let initiate_flush = inner.write_buffer().is_empty();

    inner.start_send_unpin(item.clone())?;

    if initiate_flush {
        ready!(self.svc_notify.delegate_poll(|cx| <MyStream as SinkExt<String>>::poll_flush_unpin(inner, cx)))?;
    // ... or
    // self.svc_notify.notify();
    ...
```

(naturally that task should be running `inner.flush()` in `select!` wrapped in a loop. You'll have to use `poll_fn()` and `RefCell` to be able to borrow `&mut` momentarily during related `poll` calls)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to built aforementioned `Waker` for service task

When you are not an executor (“top-level” non-async code that *owns the task to be polled*), you are never *constructing* a `Waker` — you only use a `Waker` that already exists.

In this scenario, the service task must `await` some future you provide, and when that future is polled, its `poll()` method will be given a `Waker`. That waker is the one you need to wake in order to resume the service task. If the service task has not yet been polled, then you will not have a waker, but you also don't need one (because the task *will* be polled).

In some cases this problem can be simplified by, instead of obtaining the waker for the service task, using an async channel such as one from the `tokio::sync` module. I'm not sure whether yours is one of those cases — probably not, since you in fact want a waker to pass to `poll_flush()`, but perhaps there is a way to redesign it so it is such a case.

Comment: Not exactly. My wrapper implements `Sink`, in `start_send()` I want to call `inner.start_send()` and then *immediately* initiate flushing (via `inner.poll_flush()`) and leave rest of flushing work to service task (which should be woken up once underlying socket is ready). No constructing `Flush` future involved.

Comment: @C.M. Ah — I did not read the documentation correctly. You are right that there is no additional future involved — I will revise that paragraph.